# Plot of a function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, rational-functions

What is the plot of:
$$y=\frac{\beta(1-\alpha)x}{\alpha(1-\beta)+(\beta-\alpha)x}$$
with $0<\alpha<\beta<1$.
How do I handle the parameters? How do I compute the derivatives to check for monotonicity and concavity?

Comment: Do you know how to analyze a function like, for example, $\dfrac {2x}{3-4x}$?

Comment: @GFauxPas: No, I don't unfortunately. Can you try to explain it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the things that may help to graph the function.

$1$. Roots

- The function have a root at $x=0$

$2$. Horizontal and Vertical Asymptotes

$$x=-\frac{\alpha(1-\beta)}{\beta-\alpha} \qquad \text{Vertical Asymptote}$$
$$y=\frac{\beta(1-\alpha)}{\beta-\alpha} \qquad \text{Horizontal Asymptote}$$

$3$. The Derivative

$$y'=\frac{\alpha \beta (1-\alpha)(1-\beta)}{[(\beta-\alpha)x+(\alpha+\beta)]^2}$$
and as it is positive so it is increasing in each of its branches.

For example, for the case of $\alpha=0.25$ and $\beta=0.5$, it will look like this.

[image]

Comment: How do you get asymptotes and the derivative?

Comment: @user98139: Vertical asymptotes are the roots of the denominator. Horizontal asymptotes are the limit of the function when $x$ goes to minus or plus infinity. For the derivative, you should refer deriving laws for  a quotient.

Comment: Really nice answer.

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue: Thanks. :)

Comment: @H.R. Also, it helps me learn more about vertical and horizontal asymptotes!